# Unexpected result with $select statement using WebApi 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am working on a project using MVC 4 and WebApi 1 and it work well,
After I upgraded it to MVC 5 and WebApi 2, everything works great, except this scenario: when i use the $select statement in the query and specify some properties, the options.ApplyTo() method returns unexpected results:

```
System.Web.Http.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection`1[System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder+SelectSome`1[MvcApp.Domain.Entities.Users]]
```

Why this change, and how to convert it to IQueryable< Users> as WebApi 1?
my code here:

```
public PageResult<Users> Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
{
    ODataQuerySettings settings = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 10 };
    IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(Repository.Data, settings);
    var items = results as IEnumarable<Users>;
    // items will be null if you $select some properties!
    return new PageResult<Users>(items, null, Request.GetInlineCount().Value);
}
```

Help please.